# can't bind with server data in pusher.js

Tags: angular, pusher, pusher-js

I am following [this link](https://pusher.com/tutorials/collaborative-painting-angular) to create a collaborative drawing application. i am able to run application but **collaborative drawing is not happening**. I have successfully created `PUSHER_APP_ID`, `PUSHER_KEY`, `PUSHER_SECRET` & placed in `.env`.

Collaborative drawing code -

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const channel = this.pusher.init();
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit called :: line 142 : ", this.userId);
    channel.bind('draw', (data) => {
      console.log("line 144");
      if (data.userId !== this.userId) {
        console.log("line 146");
        data.line.forEach((position) => {
          console.log("line 148");
          this.draw(position.start, position.stop, this.guestStrokeStyle);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I can see different userid if i am hitting it in different browser. but it not going inside below loop.

```
channel.bind('draw', (data) => {
...
}
```

I can see logs from `server.js` code -

```
app.post('/draw', (req, res) => {
    console.log("draw :: in server :: ", req.body);
    pusher.trigger('painting', 'draw', req.body);
    res.json(req.body);
});
```

logs -

```
draw :: in server ::  { line:
   [ { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] },
     { start: [Object], stop: [Object] } ],
userId: 'ggfe565r-68ae-6cc6-878a-7g7j9d3b6b94' }
```

**Could anyone please help/guide, if i am doing anywhere wrong or missing anything.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing `cluster: 'eu'` to `cluster: 'ap2'`.